# Reference Material

Tags: reference-request

I am starting to get into scientific computing with a library called Deal.II and I was wondering what the community recommends as good source material that I can learn about scientific material.

About the Finite Element Method and how to setup problems within the code. How to think about the problems, etc.

Comment: Welcome to SciComp.SE. As stated here, the question is too broad. Can you specify more what do you want? Asking for references is on-topic, but you need to be more specific.

Answer (score 4):

This is probably going to get closed as off-topic, but the father of deal.II is active here, and he would point you to [the tutorials](https://www.dealii.org/8.2.0/doxygen/deal.II/Tutorial.html) and [his scientific computing lectures](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~bangerth/videos.html).

Comment: Indeed :) (on all accounts)

Comment: That's what the father of deal.II would indeed do :-)